# Leibniz formula for pi - Java

Tags: java, formula, pi

So, Leibniz's formula for pi is pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9...  I can't figure out how to use this formula in Java.  I just need some help on how to incorporate the second part into it.  I know I need a loop and I need the have a divisor variable, and that it needs plus 2 each time.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't want to give you a solution. At each step of your loop, you add `(+/-)1/(2*i+1)`  where `i` is the variable of the for loop. What is difficult here?

Comment: I suggest your write as much as you can and include it in the question. I suggest evaluated two expressions at a time. It will be slightly faster and have less rounding error.  BTW you may as well calculate PI instead of PI/4.

Comment: **You will find a nice solution on the pi approach here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053809/9345726

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, this is an optimized version

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
double pi = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i += 4) {
    pi += 8.0 / (i * (i + 2L));
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println(pi + " took " + time / 1000000 / 1e3 + " secs.");
```

prints

```
3.1415926445762157 took 1.217 secs.
```

If you change this loop to do backwards instead of forwards you get a more accurate. It is more accurate as the the larger numbers added at the end hides some of the cumulated rounding error for the smaller values.

```
3.141592651589793 took 1.222 secs.
```

The value should be 3.14159265359

Comment: **You will find a nice solution on the pi approach here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/70053809/9345726

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop should look something like this:

```
double sum=0;
double sign=1.0;
for(int i =1;i<=limit;i+=2)
{
    sum+=sign/i;
    sign* =-1;
}
```

Comment: Or `sign*=-1; sum+=sign/i;`

Comment: ok sign = sign*-1; can be replaced by sign*=-1;

Comment: This will be *much* faster if you can remove the `if` condition.

Comment: incorporated the change! A lot more concise now.