# Estimate PI with series expansion using loops

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, pi

I need to estimate PI by doing following series:

```
m(i) = 4( 1- 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 ...)
```

And this is what I've done so far:

```
 float mOfI = 1;
    System.out.println("i \t \t \t \t  m(i)" );
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        float sum = i + 2;
        mOfI += 4 * (1 - (1 / sum));
        mOfI -= 4 * (1 - (1 / sum));
        System.out.println(i + "\t \t \t \t" +mOfI);
    }
```

I know I'm missing many rules here, but how can I make it to work correctly? I mean the math logic. How can I can solve it correctly?

Please Note the `-+` in the series and all numbers are odd so i can't use `i%2`.

Estimated PI would be like `4.0000 , 3.1515, 3.1466 .....` and so on.

Also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455210/write-a-program-to-estimate-pi-%CF%80-using-the-leibniz-series-in-java)  didn't received a well answer (there is no real PI value estimated)

Comment: Where is the problem? Why does it not work? Please highlight it.

Comment: @Zabuza because it doesn't do the series correctly.

Comment: Yeah, obvious. What is the series it currently produces? You will far quicker get help if you highlight that.

Comment: First off, use BigInteger for this kind of precision.

Comment: @Zabuza no that's not all,  what about different `+-` and this seriest estimated PI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a program to estimate PI (π) using the Leibniz series in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455210/write-a-program-to-estimate-pi-%cf%80-using-the-leibniz-series-in-java)

Comment: @Zabuza the question doesn't received a well answer..

Comment: @android The question itself was edited and contains a working code which solves your issue. Explanation why your current code does not work is given here.

Comment: @Zabuza no, not right, the question you mention doesn't give a right value for PI, btw i solved it in my answer below, thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your time, but i got the right solution:

```
  double start = 1;         // Start series
    double end   = 901;     // End series
    System.out.println("\ni           m(i)     ");
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    for (double i = start; i <= end; i += 100) {
        System.out.printf("%-12.0f", i);
        System.out.printf("%-6.4f\n", estimatePI(i));
    }
}

/** Method estimatePI */
public static double estimatePI(double n) {
    double pi = 0;      // Set pi to 0
    for (double i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
        pi += Math.pow(-1, i +1) / (2 * i - 1);
    }
    pi *= 4;
    return pi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple, find the easy patter. Here is a hint

1. Ignore the multiplication with 4 at first ( or you can consider it
   with each term)
2. Consider the initial denom = 1, so term = 1/denom = 1
3. Find the pattern. Note that at every step newTerm =
   `(-1)*(1/(denom+2))`. So at every iteration, update the sum and denom
   accordingly.
4. After n iteration, just multiply sum with 4

Comment: what about different `-+` in the same series ?

Answer (score 0):

```
float m = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(i%2==0){
           m +=4/(2*i+1);
        } else {
           m -=4/(2*i+1);
        }
        System.out.println(i + "\t \t \t \t" +m);
    }
```

note: i am on mobile app, there might be syntax errors but you should get the idea.

Comment: did you see the series ? it's all odd numbers, there will be one condition indeed

Comment: did you run the code? it gives Gregory-Leibniz Series.

Comment: I really would like to know the reason of down vote.

Comment: Please also give explanations, not just code only. Especially for a beginner this will be far more helpful. At least that may be the reason of the vote.

Answer (score 0):

`mOfI` will never change because these two lines cancel out each other

```
    mOfI += 4 * (1 - (1 / sum));
    mOfI -= 4 * (1 - (1 / sum));
```

Try this.

```
double mOfI = 4.0;
System.out.println("i \t \t \t \t  m(i)" );
for (int i = 1, d = 3, s = -1;
         i < n; 
         i++, d += 2, s = -s) {
    mOfI += 4.0 / (s * d);
    System.out.println(i + "\t \t \t \t" +mOfI);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why your code solves the issue? It also looks quite complex, especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.

1. First you should only divide **one** summand by `i` and the other by `i + 2`, not both by `i + 2`.
2. You add `1` to every summand, that is wrong, it should rather be like `1 / sum` instead of `1 - (1 / sum)`
3. Next `i` needs to advance more in each step, `i+2` or even `i+4` if you decide to create both summands in one iteration step
4. You quickly reach the limits of `int` and `double` precision if `n` gets bigger, you may need `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` which provide an *unlimited precision* in cost of space.

The series you are currently producing looks like:

```
4 * ((1 - 1 / 1) - (1 - 1 / 1) + (1 - 1 / 2) - (1 - 1 / 2) +- ...)
```

Which should be `0` since each part eliminates each other.

---

A correct version would look like:

```
double result = 0;

// Whether we add or subtract the summand
boolean doAdd = true;
// Start at i = 0 to produce 1 as first denominator,
// else use - instead of + in the code
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Advance in steps of 2 and use odd values
    // Denominator will be 1, 3, 5, 7, ... for i = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
    double summand = 1 / (2 * i + 1);

    if (doAdd) {
        // Add it
        result += summand;
    } else {
        // Subtract it
        result -= summand;
    }
    // Toggle the flag
    doAdd = !doAdd;
}

// Multiply by 4
result *= 4;
```

Of course, as said before, you may need to substitute by `BigDecimal`.

You can also use `if (i % 2 == 0)` instead of `if (doAdd)` if you don't want to use an extra flag. But that way it might be more easy to understand.

Comment: thanks, do you this `doAdd != doAdd` would be legal syntax?

Comment: This is legal syntax. It toggles the state of the `boolean`. For example if its current value is `true` it will be: `doAdd = !true` which is `false`. And if its currently `false` it will be `doAdd = !false` which is `true`.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course I meant `doAdd = !doAdd;`, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Java 9 exercise in functional programming; you can calculate PI with this line:

```
double pi = 4 * Stream.iterate(1.0, i -> i < 10000000, i -> i + 2)
            .reduce(0.0, (a, d) -> ((d - 1) / 2) % 2 == 0 ? (a + 1 / d) : (a - 1 / d));
```

Java 8 and Java 9 examples:

```
// Java 9
double pi = 4 * Stream.iterate(1.0, i -> i < 10000000, i -> i + 2)
        .reduce(0.0, (a, d) -> ((d - 1) / 2) % 2 == 0 ? (a + 1 / d) : (a - 1 / d));
System.out.println(pi);
// Java 8
pi = 4 * Stream.iterate(1.0, i -> i + 2).limit(10000000)
        .reduce(0.0, (a, d) -> ((d - 1) / 2) % 2 == 0 ? (a + 1 / d) : (a - 1 / d));
System.out.println(pi);
```

Comment: i'm using java 8

Comment: I have added also a Java 8 example. This is just to demonstrate that you can do the same thing with functional style in Java. There are for sure other ways to accomplish the same task.